# How to convert Angular clientHttp to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, httprequest, http-get

I have the following code that works in Angular and wish to convert it to node can someone plase help?

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

private getDeviceIP(){
    this.clientHttp.get("http://api.ipify.org/?format=json").subscribe((res:any)=>{
            this.userIpAddress = res.ip;            
        });
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that logic in `NodeJS` be aware that `NodeJS` server is the one that will send the request, so you will got his IP address, and not IP address of the client.

If you still want to implement the same logic in `NodeJs`, you can use `axios` (Promise based HTTP client), like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const getDeviceIP = (req, res, next) => {
  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://api.ipify.org/?format=json'
  }).then((response) => {
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, ip_address: response.data.ip })
  }).catch((error) => {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case (see caveat below), this is *already* converted to Node!

If you use the [`@angular/common`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/common), [`typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) and [`xmlhttprequest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) packages, you can use the following:

```typescript
import { XMLHttpRequest } from 'xmlhttprequest';
import { HttpClient, HttpXhrBackend } from '@angular/common/http';

// Your unmodified class
class Main {
  userIpAddress: any;

  constructor (private clientHttp: HttpClient) {}

  getDeviceIP () {
    this.clientHttp.get('http://api.ipify.org/?format=json').subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.userIpAddress = res.ip;
    });
  }
}

// Manually perform the dependency resolution
const backend = new HttpXhrBackend({
  build: (): XMLHttpRequest => new XMLHttpRequest()
});
const client = new HttpClient(backend);
const main = new Main(client);

// Run it!
main.getDeviceIP();
```

which can be transpiled with:

```
npx tsc --lib dom,es2015 main.ts
```

and run with:

```
node main.js
```

#### Caveat

Note the use of `dom` as a library in transpilation; this is required because the `@angular/common/http` subpackage isn't properly decoupled from the DOM related parts of `@angular/core`. For the purposes of making requests with a `HttpClient` with a Node compatible backend, this is fine, but attempting to convert more DOM related tasks will likely run into issues.